# Lyx: british english

Tags: lyx

I'm not able to get the spell checker on British english.
I have:

`Document>Settings>Language: Language = English (UK)`

`Tools>Preferences>Language Settings>Spellchecker: Spellchecker engine = Enchant`

When switching to `hunspell` ([LyX Install Not Recognizing Installed Spellcheck Dictionaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258191)) along with /usr/share/hunspell, then it says `spell checker has no dictionaries`.

Do I have to install anything on opensuse? Do I need root-rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found in `/usr/share/myspell` was only:

```
de_DE.aff  en_US.aff  hyph_de_DE.dic  th_de_DE_v2.dat  th_en_US_v2.dat
de_DE.dic  en_US.dic  hyph_en_US.dic  th_de_DE_v2.idx  th_en_US_v2.idx
```

Since I have no root rights, I created `~/.local/share/myspell` and retrieved the dict manually from somewhere:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ropensci/hunspell/master/inst/dict/en_GB.aff 
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ropensci/hunspell/master/inst/dict/en_GB.dic
```

I set spellchecker to `hunspell` and the path of `>Tools>Preference/Path>Hunspell directories` to `~/.local/share/myspell`.

I have not figured out, from where `enchant` retrieves the dicts.

Comment: The question says "since I have no root rights", @Davislor

Comment: @pst Good point! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just added Document>Settings>Language: Language = English (UK)
It works. The spell checker detects for example, minimisation as a correct word.